# RDD map function working differently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have below code, in general a map function is a higher order function which takes a function in its argument and evaluates the elements using the function.
But in this case map is not taking a function but a Map type. Not able to understand how map function is working?

```
Spark context available as sc (master = yarn-client, app id = application_1473775536920_2711).
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> val pws = Map("Apache Spark" -> "http://spark.apache.org/", "Scala" -> "http://www.scala-lang.org/")
pws: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(Apache Spark -> http://spark.apache.org/, Scala -> http://www.scala-lang.org/)

scala> val websites = sc.parallelize(Seq("Apache Spark", "Scala")).map(pws).collect
16/09/23 02:50:15 WARN util.ClosureCleaner: Expected a closure; got scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 2]16/09/23 02:50:31 WARN cluster.YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
websites: Array[String] = Array(http://spark.apache.org/, http://www.scala-lang.org/)
```

Answer (score 6):

The trait `Map[A, +B]` extends the trait `Function1[-T1, +R]`. In other words, a `Map` **is** a function. In your case you have a `Map[String, String]` which means that your map will have `def apply(arg: String): String` which is what's applied to all the elements in your `RDD`.

So even in plain Scala you can do something like

```
val m = Map(("a" -> "b"), ("c" -> "d"))
val s = Seq("a", "c")

s.map(m)
res0: Seq[String] = List(b, d)
```

For this to compile the types in `m` and `s` need to match.